# FFMPEG optimisation with Mac Studio M1 Max chip

Tags: mac, ffmpeg, video, cpu

I have been trying to Software Encode with my Mac Studio M1 Max.  I have got a script that I used on my 2012 MBP & 2017 iMac Intel i5.

On the iMac i5 I would get 3-5fps, on the MBP i7 6-8fps but on the fancy new Mac Studio M1 Max I have used the same file and same script and I get a Max avg 3fps.

I have looked into the problem and it seems that when it comes to Software encoding that FFMPEG isnt full optimised with the M1 Max chip.  I havent tried to compile or build ffmpeg myself as my skills arent that good.  Im wondering if FFMPEG are looking to fix this in future releases or if the community can give me some help on where I am going wrong or need to do to get ffmpeg fully optimised and working better on the M1 Max as its not great that a 10 year old intel i7 smashes the performance of an M1 Max chip.

I have tried Hardware encoding but the quality is crap and want to continue to use my script but with the full speeds the M1 Max can give

Many thank in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Specifically, you should provide some details about your copy of ffmpeg (where did you get it, what version is it, what architecture is it compiled for (x86 or ARM)).